# Xcode Recent Projects

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to access the recent projects list the Xcode stores in terminal by calling:

```
$defaults read com.apple.Xcode NSRecentXCProjectDocuments
```

I get an error that says:

```
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.Xcode, NSRecentXCProjectDocuments) does not exist
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defaults read com.apple.Xcode
{
    NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows = 0;
}
```

It means the value you are looking for is not in the .plist file, for that bundle. The defaults file can only read those values in the files in folder ~/Library/Preferences/.

Comment: Ok thanks. In my Preferences folder, I don't see any file named com.apple.Xcode.plist though. Do you know why that is?